# Xcode issue Type 'XYZController' does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS project and after implementing a 3rd party library to my project via Pods, I'm getting an error:

> Type 'XYZController' does not conform to protocol

When I click on the error and I add the protocol subs, Xcode adds the already implemented function (`cardForItemAt()`).

However, when I created a new project from scratch, and implemented it the very same way, I don't have any error messages.

Anyone has any idea what can cause this issue? What can I do in this case?
I've cleaned the build, the derived data, and restarted Xcode, but same error.

Here is my ViewController which fails:

```
import UIKIt
import VerticalCardSwiper

class MainViewController: UIViewController, VerticalCardSwiperDelegate, VerticalCardSwiperDatasource  {
    private var cardSwiper: VerticalCardSwiper!

    private var contactsDemoData: [Contact] = [
        Contact(name: "John Doe", age: 33),
        Contact(name: "Chuck Norris", age: 78),
        Contact(name: "Bill Gates", age: 62),
        Contact(name: "Steve Jobs", age: 56)
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cardSwiper = VerticalCardSwiper(frame: self.view.bounds)
        cardSwiper.delegate = self
        cardSwiper.datasource = self
        cardSwiper.register(MainCard.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainCard")
        view.addSubview(cardSwiper)
    }

    func cardForItemAt(verticalCardSwiperView: VerticalCardSwiperView, cardForItemAt index: Int) -> CardCell {
        let cardCell = verticalCardSwiperView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainCard", for: index) as! MainCard
        let _ = contactsDemoData[index]
        cardCell.setRandomBackgroundColor()
        return cardCell
    }

    func numberOfCards(verticalCardSwiperView: VerticalCardSwiperView) -> Int {
        return contactsDemoData.count
    }

    func willSwipeCardAway(card: CardCell, index: Int, swipeDirection: SwipeDirection) {
        // called right before the card animates off the screen.
    }

    func didSwipeCardAway(card: CardCell, index: Int, swipeDirection: SwipeDirection) {
        contactsDemoData.remove(at: index)
    }
}

class MainCard: CardCell {
    public func setRandomBackgroundColor(){
        let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
        let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
        let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

I don't use storyboards at all in the project.

Comment: You may need to show some sample code to help people get the situation.

Comment: Updated with the code

Comment: @RichardPap there must be some difference in the already implemented function and the function declared in the protocol. Just compare both carefully OR share the function added by Xcode.

Comment: I tried to replace with the protocol sub it offers, but its the very same. Even when i replace the existing function with it, gives the very same error. So they are the same.

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of this Cocoapod, are you still having this issue?